# Using PEG.js for simple search/replace

Tags: peg, pegjs

Im trying to understand how to use PEG.js for simple search/replace in a text. Surely this is not the intended use for a parser but anyway Im curious about the logic behind these kind of languages to produce some search/replace.

The problem that Im having is that is hard to define positively the complementary of some definitions. An example: imagine I want to search and replace something like this syntax:

```
rule = (whatever_is_not_my_syntax* m:my_syntax)+ {replace m}
word = [a-z0-9_]+
my_syntax = word "." word
whatever_is_not_my_syntax = ???
```

It is hard to describe, positively, what is `whatever_is_not_my_syntax` in PEG.js without partial collision (and consequent parser error) with `my_syntax`, or at least I dont know how to do it, because the only negative parser functions on PEG.js are `!expression` and `[^characters]`.

Can you help me? I will appreciate any book or bibliography, if exists, about this topic. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to specify what's not in your syntax. First try to match your syntax, then have a fallback for anything else.

Here `rule` is a list of all patterns in your syntax. When it doesn't match, `other` will match instead.

```
expr =
    a:rule " " b:expr
        {return [a].concat(b)}
  / a:rule
        {return [a]}
  / a:other " " b:expr
        {return [a].concat(b)}
  / a:other
        {return [a]}

word =
    a:[a-z0-9_]+
        {return a.join("")}

rule =
    word "." word
        {return "rule1"} // Put replace logic here
  / word ":" word
        {return "rule2"} // Put replace logic here

other =
    word
        {return "other"}
```

You can try it online: http://pegjs.org/online

Answer (score 1):

You were close, we only big difference is the order:

Instead of `whatever_is_not_my_syntax* m:my_syntax` should be `m:my_syntax whatever_is_not_my_syntax`. Note that using in this case generates error:

```
Line 1, column 15: Possible infinite loop when parsing (repetition used with an expression that may not consume any input).
```

So instead of `whatever_is_not_my_syntax*` just `whatever_is_not_my_syntax` is enough.

```
root = result:(rules / whatever_is_not_my_syntax)* { return result.join(""); }

rules = 
  my_syntax /
  else_syntax

else_syntax = word ":" word { return "replace2" }

my_syntax = word "." word { return "replace1" }

word = [a-z0-9_]+

whatever_is_not_my_syntax = .
```

Input of:

```
a x:y b x.y c
```

Will be transformed as:

```
"a replace2 b replace1 c"
```

You can try it online: http://pegjs.org/online

[image]